# User profile showing up twice in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem

Ok. So, I'm not sure where to begin here but here it goes!

Can someone tell me where the "Org Chart" (SP on-Prem 2016) on sharepoint pulls user info from? I show a user who's name displays twice. One instance from our old domain (no longer exists) and another instance from our current and existing domain. This is causing an issue and I can't find anything that can lead me to edit it other than the UIL which is not editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created UPS and imported users from AD to SP?
You could go to the CA to check if you can find the users you want:

[image]

or re-synchronize to see if it works.
[image]

Comment: This worked!! Thanks so much for your assistance!